# Short story about a guy who rescues people by tracking their fear

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short story I read years ago in a collection I guess.  There is a guy who can rescue people by tracking down their fear.  I remember very little except that at one point he consults a tea leaf reader for information. I am guessing this is from the 70s.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Fear Hound](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50559) (1968) by Katherine MacLean

George is pulled into helping his friend Ahmed from the Rescue Squad due to a high sensitivity to the projected emotions of others.  Together they use his experiences of fear, thirst, and pain to track down a woman who is injured and in need of assistance.  Along the way, they visit a tea leaf reader who offers them guidance.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks.